# Apache Httpcomponent Fluent API hangs after some IO errors

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, fluent

I am using **Apache Http Fluent API 4.3.2** for making periodic HTTPS requests to a not very reliable API. My code looks like this:

```
try {
    Request get = Request.Get(url);
    get.connectTimeout(10000);
    get.socketTimeout(10000);
    Executor executor = Executor
        .newInstance(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
    String response = executor.execute(get).returnContent().asString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Http get threw an exception", e);
}
```

It can work for a couple of days and then throw

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

hundreds of times from `execute` method.

After some quantity of exceptions method `execute` blocks forever.
I can suggest that the executor runs out of connections, but don't know what to do with that.

No answer for a month? I'm ready to accept an answer like "There is no solution".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that after some 404 errors Fluent hangs.

I fixed it by aborting the request.

```
req.abort();
```

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.html#abort()